# How to display image in its actual size with a ScrollViewer using WPF?

Tags: wpf, image, scrollview

I want to display image in its actual size with a ScrollViewer. I've put the Image Control in a scrollviewer but found that the scrollviewer has no effect. The picture shows is either resized to fit the Image Control or only show a part of it, with no scrollbar. What's the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stretch="None"
and if nedded HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" on the scrollViewer

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Image Source="C:\Untitled.bmp" Stretch="None"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried and it works, also I found that you must set the Height and Width property in order to make it work properly.